# How to return a list using router in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

In the code, if it is done using (@app.post('/...')), it runs without any problems, but if it is done using (@router.post('/...')), it gives the following error;
TypeError: Cannot instantiate typing.Union

code:

```
router = APIRouter()

@app.get("/api/accounts/userslist/{domain}",
          response_description="List all users")
async def account_list(
    domain: str,
    credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Security(security)):
    token = credentials.credentials
    if (auth_handler.decode_token(token)):
        domain = domains_db.find_one({'domain': domain})
        if domain == None:
            return JSONResponse(
                status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                content='There is no user matching the requested domain.')
        else:
            accounts = users_db.find({'domain': domain['domain_id']})
            list_account = [AuthModel(**account) for account in accounts]
            return list_account
```

model:

```
class AuthModel(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    userid: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    firstname: Optional[str]
    lastname: Optional[str]
    domain: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    email: EmailStr
    phone: Optional[str]
    plain_secret: Optional[str]
    status: Optional[str]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the router in the app in your main.py file as described here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#include-the-apirouters-for-users-and-items ?